# Will ionic-native Push Notifications work in a browser?

Tags: push-notification, ionic2, ionic-native

I am about to implement [ionic-native Push Notifications](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/push/).  Will this work in a browser, or do I need to install a iOS/Android Emulator?

Comment: Native plugins not working in browser, you have install emulators or deploy the app on a real device

Answer (score 0):

It won't work on Browsers unless you use the Phonegap Push Server. Please refer to the [Phonegap Push Plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#browser-details) documentation.

> Browser details
>
> Browser quirks
>
> For the time being push support on the browser will only work using
>   the PhoneGap push server.
>
> When you run phonegap serve to test browser push point your browser at
>   http://localhost:3000. The browser push implementation uses the W3C
>   Push Spec's implementation which relies on ServiceWorkers and
>   ServiceWorkers can only be accessed via the https protocol or via
>   http://localhost. Pointing your browser at localhost will be the
>   easiest way to test.
>
> Browser Support
>
> Chrome 49+ Firefox 46+

NB: In order to make it work in an Android emulator, a special configuration is required. I recommend using a real device, if you can. Plus, the iOS simulator is not able (not at all) to simulate push notifications. In that case, you must use a real device.